# Forecast calculation

Tags: r, excel-formula, formula, calculation, forecast

How can I calculate the forecast per quarter for the following fields?

```
2023 Q4
2024 Q1
2024 Q2
2024 Q3
2024 Q4
```

based on the following data:

```
total 2022: 228 000
2023 Q1: 45000
2023 Q2: 53400
2023 Q3: 25000
```

Can you help me please?

the formula to calculate the forecast per quarter.

Comment: linear regression? machine-learning? non-linear regression? seasonal (arima)?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Daniela! Questions on SO need to be concrete, and especially in the [tag:r] tag they should include clear close, errors/warnings if appropriate, sample data, expected output, and when most of those are absent, some indication of research to indicate what direction you're headed in, what you found, and why it does not work for this case. I don't know of any StackExchange sites that are intended to be used as complete *tutorials* or *lesson plans*, and SO is no exception.

Comment: Without some additional information any contributions here would be just speculative guesses. You have 3 quarterly data points and an annual total and want to forecast the next 5 quarters. Is there an expectation that the data follow a seasonal pattern or that there is a long term trend or that there is autocorrelation or any one of a whole range of influences that might be included within a forecasting model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To forecast future values based on historical data, various methods are available. A simple approach is to use linear regression, while more sophisticated methods might involve time series analysis using models like ARIMA, ETS, or Prophet.

**Let's take a simple approach using linear regression with R:**

1. Assign a numerical value to each quarter.
2. Fit a linear regression model using these numerical values as the
   independent variable and the sales figures as the dependent
   variable.
3. Predict the future values using the fitted model.

**Here's how you can do it:**

```
# Load necessary libraries
library(lmtest)

# Data
quarters <- c("2022", "2023 Q1", "2023 Q2", "2023 Q3")
sales <- c(228000/4, 45000, 53400, 25000)  # 2022 value is divided by 4 to estimate a quarterly average

# Convert quarters to numerical values
# Assuming that 2022 corresponds to an average of its quarters
quarter_nums <- c(4.5, 5, 6, 7) 

# Fit a linear model
model <- lm(sales ~ quarter_nums)

# Predict for the future quarters
future_quarters <- c(8, 9, 10, 11, 12) # corresponding to 2023 Q4 to 2024 Q4
predictions <- predict(model, newdata = data.frame(quarter_nums = future_quarters))

# Print the forecasts
names(predictions) <- c("2023 Q4", "2024 Q1", "2024 Q2", "2024 Q3", "2024 Q4")
print(predictions)
```

Remember, this is a simple linear regression approach and assumes that the trend from your provided data will continue. If there are seasonal variations, sudden shocks, or other factors, this method might not capture them. For more accurate forecasting, consider using time-series forecasting packages like `forecast` and methods like **ARIMA** or **ETS**.

Also, the forecast assumes that the given total for 2022 (228,000) is evenly spread across the four quarters, which might not be accurate. If you have the breakdown for each quarter in 2022, it would improve the accuracy of the forecast.